# Can I force nohup output to the screen instead of a file?

Tags: linux, nohup

When I run a script with nohup, the output is forced to the out.log file by default; is there a way to force the output to the screen instead of the file? I need to be able to see when my script gives me a "process started" message, and I don't want to clog up the system with log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would defeat the purpose of nohup, use `tail -f out.log` instead.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I only really need to check output for a little while until I get a "JBoss started" message, so a tail should work. It wouldn't be a hassle to delete the log manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you run bash, you can put it into the background, and then use `disown` to have it not shut down when bash closes.  So your output is to the terminal, but you can close the terminal and still have your app run.